# How can I keep pseudo elements active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner of coding and this is the first post for me.

I could make link buttons I liked except for one thing, which is I needed to keep pushing a mouse down to get the desired effect. I mean, if I unclick it, the effects all come back and that's not what I want. I want to stop the effect and jump to a linked site. I want the effect occurred by click to be finished and stabilized.

I though the easy way to fix it was to add a .active class using JQuery, however, pseudo elements cannot be selected by JQuery and seems really complicated for me.
I want only "ul li:before, ul li:after, ul li .fa" to have .active, I don't want other elements such as "ul li .fa" to have .active.

I'm sorry for my bad explanation.
However, I'd appreciate if you could help me, desirably, showing me the completed result.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

ul li { /*black border*/
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li .fa { /*arrengement of icons*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  font-size:  48px;
  color: #262626;
}
ul li:hover .fa { /*make icons white when hovered*/
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li:before { /*pink circles invisible due to opacity:0*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e91e63;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li:hover:before { /*show pink circles when hovered*/
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(.8);
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li:after { /*dotted borders invisible due to opacity:0*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  /* border: 2px dashed #262626; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 2px dashed #262626;
  border-right: 2px dashed #262626;
  border-left: 2px dashed #262626;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #262626;
}
ul li:hover:after { /*display and rotate dotted borderes when hovered*/
  opacity: 1;
  animation: rotateborder 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotateborder {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.92) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.92) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

ul li:active:before, ul li:active .fa { /*sublimate pink circles and icons when clicked*/
  transform: scale(20);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
ul li:active:after { /*dipslay and rotate dotted borders when clicked*/
  opacity: 1;
  animation: spin 1s linear ;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;

}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.92) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0) rotate(1500deg);
  }
}

main { /*overflow:hidden so that icons don't disturb the size of the window because of its expansion when clicked*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <script>
    $("li").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  </script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the class (e.g: `.active`) to the containing element instead; in this case the list item, and declare your selectors as follows: `ul li.active:before, ul li.active .fa`

Comment: Wait! What? "_Unclick_" How can I do something like that?

Comment: Hi thanks for you guys' answers. However, I wasn't specific enough.

If you click the icon for secs, then what's left is only black border and everything else is white. That's what I want and I want it to remain until the page jumps to the linked site.
What I don't like is that pink and the icon come back again.

Usually, people click the link for maybe less than 0.1 seconds. But if so, I want the animation to complete until only black border and white remains.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I've solved the problem.
As @UncaughtTypeError and Rambobafet suggested, what I needed to do was to add .active instead of :active, then used JQuery $("li").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("active");
});
Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your problem or where you're heading to.

You can't add class to a pseudo element (because, well it's not a real element hence the "pseudo"), but you can style pseudo element with a class with CSS.

```
ul li.active::before, 
ul li.active::after{
     /* Your style */
}
```

So I guess, your final style of animation should be "stabilized" in CSS with a dedicated class.
If the active class is used for something else, then use a dedicated class for your pseudo element (.active-pseudo or whatever seems right to you)
If you absolutely need class for your pseudo elements, then use real elements (span etc.) and forget ::before and ::after. :)